# algorithm that assign object to cluster based on questions

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, cluster-analysis

I need algorithm that assign object to cluster already created.
In my case objects are Patients or sick person and clusters are diseases, and based on multiple questions patient should be assigned to cluster; of course the questions and responses (yes or no) will be already prepared for every disease.

For example : you are coughing ? if yes => do you have a fever? if Yes then maybe => corona disease.
and so on.
edit : decision tree algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [ID-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_algorithm); this allows you to build a decision tree based on pre-classified data, and any new patient can be classified according to their responses.